# NoMethodError in Welcome#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, controller, undefined

Im new to rails, and I have an app with a Video model, controller and views.

Im figuring out how to query and display the videos I want and so far so good when Im using the video controller.

I have a homepage where I want to display the most important video of the week so I made a welcome controller with an index action as the tutorial said.

Inside the welcome controller I have:

```
    class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

      def index
        @highlighted_video = Video.where("highlight = true")
      end

    end
```

highlight is a boolean attribute. And the index view:

```
    <iframe width="100%" height="315" src="<%= @highlighted_video.url %>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But I get the following error (url is another video attribute in my db):

```
     undefined method `url' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Video:0x2507760>
```

I thought this would've worked as in the video controller but it doesn't please help.

Comment: are you trying to get the first record with highlight value as true ?

Answer (score 1):

I would keep my controller skinny. Assuming I want to return the first record that is highlighted, I would add a [scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) to the `Video` model:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  scope :highlighted, -> { where(highlight: true).first }
  # ...
end
```

This will return the *first* record that is highlighted. Then in controller I would just do:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @highlighted_video = Video.highlighted
  end

end
```

Then the code in your view should work just fine, supposing you have defined the `#url` method in the model.

Comment: @user3099920 Glad to hear! You might as well *accept* the answer if it solved your issue :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get the first record try this

```
@highlighted_video = Video.where("highlight = true").first
```

Be careful when you access the attributes of @highlighted_video instance variable, if there isn't no record matching your query, it will return nil value, where you will get error undefined method url for nil class.

Answer (score 0):

you can't  call `url` method on `@highlighted_video`

in this variable you have array of `video`

```
  def index
    @highlighted_video = Video.where("highlight = true")
  end
```

on index.html.erb

```
  <% @highlighted_video.each do |video| %>
     <iframe width="100%" height="315" src="<%= video.url %>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: I am just looking for a single video but I now know that WHERE returns an array. What if I use the FIND method?